# leiningen project: repl-options/init

Tags: clojure, leiningen

When I add `:repl-options {:init (print "x..")}` to ~/.lein/profiles.clj it does what it should on every repl start-up. however, when I add the same to my local project.clj, I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: do in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init5885833654225579206.clj:1:886)
```

I'm using leiningen 2.5.3

Comment: Have you tried updating to the latest version? I have 2.6.1 and can't reproduce your problem. Also, are you sure your :repl-options key is at the right level in the project.clj file?

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled across this issue as well - I tried to use multiple profiles, each with its own `:repl-options`.
The issue is that Leiningen doesn't merge `:init: correctly. You can refer to [this issue](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/878) for more details.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any fix that would work for me. And the issue itself won't be fixed till Leiningen 3.0.